# UserManager throws exception about IdentityRoleId

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have an MVC 5 project with individual account auth, and two simple capture screens.

All was working fine, until I decided to grant a user a role on registration, so in the post action for `Register`, after `UserManager.CreateAsync`, if successful, I added:

```
 UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, IdentityData.RoleNames.GeneralAdmin);
```

Then it threw `SqlException: Invalid column name 'IdentityRoleId'`.

Now it throws this exception any time I use `UserManager`, even `UserManager.CreateAsync`, before I have even tried to grant a role. The string `IdentityRoleId` does not occur anywhere in the project, and it was Identity that created its own tables, using the column name `RoleId`.

I must add that when I started the project, I had two `DbContext` classes, one with my business entities, and the auto-generated `ApplicationDbContext`, which has the Identity models deeply hidden somewhere. Yet even on decompiling this context, I see only `RoleId` in `IdentityUserRoles`.

A profiler traces shows this query, from where I have no idea - it's nowhere in my code. I expect it happens when a user is loaded, and that User's Roles are loaded:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    1 AS [C1], 
    [Extent1].[RoleId] AS [RoleId], 
    [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
    [Extent1].[IdentityRoleId] AS [IdentityRoleId]
    FROM [dbo].[IdentityUserRoles] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[UserId] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=N'd299ba29-5266-40a2-b6cd-404588926a5b'
```

Where is this phantom `IdentityRoleId` coming from? Where should I look, or what should I do, to trace this down. Maybe the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` is broken, or maybe EF is broken, but everything was working until that one change I made this morning, which is now completely deleted.

Comment: Very much looks like your `ApplicationRole` model is messed up and EF adds extra fields there. Can you show `ApplicationDbContext` configuration and all Identity-related classes? Also if you have EF migration related to Identity, can you show it? I had this before and problem was with inherited fields and DbContext configuration.

Comment: I just added the spare column with a migration. Now it always has value `null`, and everything else works fine. Working for me for now, but if it happens again, I'll review your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @trailmax, the `IdentityUserRoles, and all related `Identity` entities are bake into the Identity library asemblis, and not declared anywhere in my code. I think may be to do with a small glitch in the code generation for that case. It hasn't happened again.